# c# increment int variable inside foreach loop

Tags: c#

I use retroarch. It has save states and screen shots of save states. The files are named as follows.

```
game.state
game.state.png
game.state1
game.state1.png
game.state2
game.state2.png
```

and so on.

Eventually I want to be able to display the images and click on them to interact with the .state.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string path = @"C:\Users\User\Documents\Retroarch\states\";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetList();
    }

    public void GetList()
    {
        int var = 0;
        string newVar = ".state" + var;

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*");

        foreach (var fileExt in files)
        {                
            string p = fileExt;                
            string e = Path.GetExtension(p);

            if (e == ".state" || e == newVar)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(newVar); //shows .state / no others
            }

            var++;

            MessageBox.Show(newVar); //shows newVar incrementing
            MessageBox.Show(e); //shows extension
        }
    }
}
}
```

Im having trouble with my if statement

```
if (e == ".state" || e == newVar)
```

It will display the first state but no others. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dear goodness, please don't name the variable `var`.

Comment: I suggest you use `Regex` to detect the file extensions `state`,`state1` ect. I guess there is no guarantee that `foreach` loops through files in an incremental order.

Comment: ok. thank you. I'll google why naming variable var is a bad idea lol.

Comment: Additional info : Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit "type" var. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this update. I've changed only the contents of the if statement. We check if the extension begins with ".state".

```
public void GetList()
{
    int var = 0;
    string newVar = ".state" + var;

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*");

    foreach (var fileExt in files)
    {
        string p = fileExt;
        string e = Path.GetExtension(p);

        if (e.StartsWith(".state"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(newVar); //shows .state / no others
        }

        var++;

        MessageBox.Show(newVar); //shows newVar incrementing
        MessageBox.Show(e); //shows extension
    }
}
```

And, I really agree with [Jesse C. Slicer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3312/jesse-c-slicer) that it would be good to not use "var" as a variable name -- maybe change it to "suffix" for example.

Comment: I only get one message box from the if statement using this. I have 10 game.state file in the folder?

Comment: This won't work. When you iterate the next file, you are incrementing the `var` counter. The files arent exactly in incremental order: `.state0`, `.state1`, `.state2`, ...  so chance is you'll get 0 match.

Comment: Thanks guys... @egnomarator. if(e.StartsWith(".state")) works.